# merging two similiar functions with .preventDefault() - javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, function

I have two similar functions, function done and function delete.

I want to merge them together but I don't know how to merge them properly.
I did it in the back end for php but for javascript somehow I couldn't get it to work.

I have jquery for these two buttons let's say

I started with something like this which works fine and nothing wrong but I guess it'll be good for to merge them together since they are pretty similar.

```
  $('ol#textField').on('click', '.done-btn', doneButton);
  $('ol#textField').on('click', '.delete-btn', deleteButton);
```

my deleteButton and doneButtion functions

```
function deleteButton(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $clicked = $(this);
    var $cLI = $clicked.closest('li');
    var todoText = $cLI.clone().children().remove().end().text();
    var getID = $cLI.attr('id');

    $.ajax({
                // codes
        }
    });
}

function doneButton(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $clicked = $(this);
    var $cLI = $clicked.closest('li');
    var $cSpan = $clicked.closest('span');
    var todoText = $cLI.clone().children().remove().end().text();
    var getID = $cLI.attr('id');

    $.ajax({
            //codes
        }
    });
}
```

as seen they are like the same but of course except the ajax part which I didn't add in since it'll be too much codes and I don't think those codes is any concern.

so I tried something like this to combine them but doesn't work.

```
$('ol#textField').on('click', '.done-btn', doubleD('done'));
$('ol#textField').on('click', '.delete-btn', doubleD('delete'));
```

I tried to combine the function like this. so if the parameter is done then the done ajax will be called and parameter is delete then delete will be called.  I also want to add the `.preventDefault()` into the function but have no clue how to get them done.

```
function doubleD(action){
      var $clicked = $(this);
      var $cLI = $clicked.closest('li');
      var todoText = $cLI.clone().children().remove().end().text();
      var getID = $cLI.attr('id');

      if(action == 'done'){
          var $cSpan = $clicked.closest('span');
          $.ajax({
                // ajax for done
              }
          });
      }

      if(action == 'delete'){
          $.ajax({
                // ajax for delete
              }
          });
      }
  }
```

Can someone please give me a hand?

Thank you for your time and attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that jQuery doesn't pass your argument on to the handler. You have to add that as event data. Reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Try this:

```
$('ol#textField').on('click', '.done-btn', { action: 'done' }, doubleD);
$('ol#textField').on('click', '.delete-btn', { action: 'delete' }, doubleD);
```

Then you will access like this:

```
function doubleD(evt){
  var action = evt.data.action; // ACCESS THE PARAMETER HERE

  var $clicked = $(this);
  var $cLI = $clicked.closest('li');
  var todoText = $cLI.clone().children().remove().end().text();
  var getID = $cLI.attr('id');

  if(action == 'done'){
      var $cSpan = $clicked.closest('span');
      $.ajax({
            // ajax for done
          }
      });
  }

  if(action == 'delete'){
      $.ajax({
            // ajax for delete
          }
      });
  }
}
```

I don't recommend doing it this way, but you can also write it like this:

```
$('ol#textField').on('click', '.done-btn', function () {
    doubleD('done');
});
$('ol#textField').on('click', '.done-btn', function () {
    doubleD('delete');
});
```

Then, your original `doubleD` function would work.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to remember this way too. +1 for `event.data`, this is a bit better then using the class because you don't need to worry about the presentation code changing later and mucking it up.

Comment: Thank you, I guess jQuery has the parameter different from JavaScript.  I just started reading beginner JavaScript 1-2 months ago and thought it would work pretty much the same way for methods.

Comment: Well, this all has to do with passing a function by reference instead of calling a function -- which basically means you are giving the `on` method your function to call later. When jQuery calls that function, it passes the `event` object as an argument. jQuery's documentation is pretty substantial, but I'd recommend getting a good grasp of vanilla JavaScript before really diving into jQuery (not because jQuery is hard to learn, but because you'll then understand what jQuery is doing most of the time).

Answer (score 2):

have you simply tried this

```
  $('ol#textField').on('click', '.done-btn, .delete-btn', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if( $(this).hasClass('done-btn') ){

        }else{

        }

  });
```

IF not `$(this)` you can use `$(e.target)` i am pretty sure too, checking the class will tell you the button, no?

To separate the call, the main difference is the scope it's being called in.  When it's part of the event, then the `$(this)` has meaning, if it's separate then you lose that scope.  To overcome that you can use the event object which contains the `target` of the event http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_target.asp, you have to be mind full of event bubbling though but I think in this case ( using an input ) you would be ok, you could check `$(e.target).is('input[type="button"]')` if you really wanted to be safe.  Anyway:

```
$('ol#textField').on('click', '.done-btn, .delete-btn', doubleD);


function doubleD(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if( $(e.target).hasClass('done-btn') ){

    }else{

    }        
};
```

However as I said int the comments, separating the logic from the presentation ( using e.data ) has great value.  What that means is that you are not relying on the class names for the logic.  So if at a latter point you decide to change the class you don't need to update the code, because it's not relying on your presentation ( page layout and styling ).

I actually know about the other answer and planed on adding it as well, but as I don't use it much I had to do a bit of googling to make sure I remembered it correctly.  The other poster beat me to it.  Which is fine, but I wanted to point out it's actually a better method.

Also you could use a `data-` http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp attribute instead of the class, like

```
 <input type="button" class="done-btn" data-mode="done" />
```

And check it by doing

```
 if( $(this).data('mode') == 'done'  ){
  ...
```

Some may say that is not the "best practice" way of doing it so really the best way, still is to use the `event.data`.  Because while it be less relent on the presentation, there is still that element of dependency on the DOM element.

Comment: works perfectly!
But I am trying to separate the action statement or whatever it's called and the function....I will try the way @swatkin suggested and see if it works but really thank you I will keep this way in mind.

Comment: you could separate it by using `e.target` instead, but as I said in the other comments, there is something to be said of separating it from the presentation